# how to covert 24 hours to 12 hours in existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know how my sql like this my problem is every i remove my where clause in my code there have a error (Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.) i remove may where clause because i want to see my all data, the figure below is example only i have so many data

This is the 1st table

```
| Entries               | recordDate              | Empid  | Reference |             
+-----------------------+-------------------------+--------+-----------+  
| 0016930507201907:35I  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
| 0016930507201917:06O  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
| 0016930507201907:35I  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |  
|                       | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 | 001693 |   1693    |
```

2nd table

```
| LastName | FirstName | middleName | EmployeeNO |
+----------+-----------+------------+------------+
| Cruz     | MA Kimberly  | Castillo   |   001693   |
```

this is i want to see

```
| Name                    | EmployeeNO | RecordDate              | TimeIn | TimeOut | 
+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------+---------+
| CRUZ, MA  KIMBERLY, CASTILLO  |    001693  | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 |  07:35am |  05:06pm  |
| CRUZ, MA  KIMBERLY,CASTILLO   |    001693  | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 |  07:35am |
```

this is my code please help me thank you advance for your helping

```
Select 
    B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ',' + B.MiddleName[Name] ,
    A.[RecordDate],
    B.[EmployeeNO],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(08),MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', A.[Entries], 0), 1) > 0, CAST( SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS [TIME]), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeIn], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(08),MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', A.[Entries], 0), 1) > 0,CAST(SUBSTRING(A.[Entries], LEN(A.[Entries]) - 5, 5) AS [TIME]), NULL)),100) AS [TimeOut]
FROM Employees [B]
INNER JOIN [DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID
GROUP BY B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName,B.[EmployeeNO], A.[recordDate]
ORDER BY A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName +','+B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName ASC
```

Comment: where is the `TimeIn` `TimeOut` comes from ?

Comment: I *think* that's defined by the last character of `Entries`, @Squirrel.

Comment: From where the `'MA'` and `'CA'`comes from?

Comment: @Larnu I think so, by `I/O` in `Entries` column

Comment: ma is included in data in first Name

Comment: Considering that `recordDate` has a value like `2019-05-07 00:00:00 000` does that mean it's stored as a `varchar`? A value `datetime`, would finish with `.000`.

Comment: @KimberlyCruz not it isn't. The string `'Kimberly` does not contain the string `'MA'`.

Comment: please teach me how to solve it please

Comment: Well I don't see `'Ma' / 'CA'` included in `FirstName` column as you said

Comment: im sorry my bad im done edit  my work please take a look again

Comment: please help me i solving this almost a day or a week

Comment: Almost a day *or* a week? Those a quite different time scales.

Comment: this problem is 1 day but this full project almost 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

This works for the sample data you have provided. **Note** however, I *assume* that `recordDate` is a `varchar`, due to it not being a valid `datetime` value (if it were, `2019-05-07 00:00:00 000` would be `2019-05-07 00:00:00.000`; note the `.` instead of the ). If `recordDate` isn't a `varchar` then you won't need need to include the `STUFF` and `CONVERT` expressions to "fix" the value in the `VALUES` operator. Really, however, you should not be storing `date(time)` data as a `varchar`; use the appropriate data type for your data (as these values have no time portion other than midnight, `date` would seem best).

I also return the `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` columns as the datatype `time`. Date and Time datatypes, in SQL Server, don't have a format they are binary values. If you want to display it in a 12 hour format then you need to configure that in your presentation layer, not your SQL:

```
--Table1 Sample Data
WITH Table1 AS(
    SELECT V.Entries,
           V.recordDate,
           V.Empid,
           V.Reference
    FROM (VALUES('0016930507201907:35I','2019-05-07 00:00:00 000','001693',1693),  
                ('0016930507201917:06O','2019-05-07 00:00:00 000','001693',1693),  
                ('0016930507201907:35I','2019-05-08 00:00:00 000','001693',1693),  
                (NULL,'2019-05-08 00:00:00 000','001693',1693)) V(Entries,recordDate,Empid,Reference)),
--Table2 Sample Data
Table2 AS (
    SELECT 'Cruz' AS LastName,
           'MA Kimberly' AS FirstName,
           'Castillo' AS middleName,
           '001693' AS EmployeeNO)
--Solution
SELECT STUFF(CONCAT(', ' + T2.LastName, ', ' + T2.FirstName, ', ' + T2.middleName),1,2,'') AS [Name],
       T2.EmployeeNO,
       T1.recordDate,
       MAX(CONVERT(time(0),CASE S.InOut WHEN 'I' THEN SUBSTRING(T1.Entries,15,5) END)) AS TimeIn,
       MAX(CONVERT(time(0),CASE S.InOut WHEN 'O' THEN SUBSTRING(T1.Entries,15,5) END)) AS TimeOut
FROM Table1 T1
     JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Empid = T2.EmployeeNO --These should really have the same name
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(T1.recordDate,11,1, 'T'),20,1,'.')),RIGHT(T1.Entries,1))) S(recordDate, InOut)
GROUP BY T2.EmployeeNO,
         T1.recordDate,
         T2.LastName,
         T2.FirstName,
         T2.middleName;
```

Comment: what about the conversion of the time (12 hours to 24 hours)

Comment: I discuss that, @KimberlyCruz , in the answer: *"If you want to display it in a 12 hour format then you need to configure that in your presentation layer, not your SQL"*

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are after?

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT EmployeeNO,
         CONCAT(LastName, ',', FirstName, ',', MiddleName) Name,
         RecordDate,
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(Entries, 1) = 'I' 
              THEN CAST(REPLACE(RIGHT(Entries, 6), 'I', '') AS TIME)
         END TimeIn,
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(Entries, 1) = 'O' 
              THEN CAST(REPLACE(RIGHT(Entries, 6), 'O', '') AS TIME)
         END TimeOut     
  FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
  ON T1.EmpId = T2.EmployeeNO
)
SELECT EmployeeNO,
       Name,
       RecordDate,
       MIN(TimeIn) TimeIn,
       MAX(TimeOut) TimeOut
FROM CTE
GROUP BY EmployeeNO,
         Name,
         RecordDate;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+
| EmployeeNO |          Name          |       RecordDate        |  TimeIn  | TimeOut  |
+------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+
|       1693 | Cruz,Kimberly,Castillo | 2019-05-07 00:00:00 000 | 07:35:00 | 17:06:00 |
|       1693 | Cruz,Kimberly,Castillo | 2019-05-08 00:00:00 000 | 07:35:00 |          |
+------------+------------------------+-------------------------+----------+----------+
```

**[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e212654f98d334bd5f1cf6cc1e4767d)**

---

Now, let's talk a bit about the real problems you have.

You are storing dates as string which is bad, always pick the right data type for your data, so you need to store dates as `DATE`. Also for the `Entries` has 3 info there, that means a lack of normalization, because it should be 3 column instead.
For example

```
+----------------+------+---------------------+
|    Entries     | Kind |      EntriesDate    |
+----------------+------+---------------------+
| 00169305072019 |    1 | 2019-05-07 07:35:00 |
| 00169305072019 |    0 | 2019-05-07 16:30:00 |
+----------------+------+---------------------+
```

This way, you won't fall in those issues and things becomes easy.

For the concatenation of the names, if you always needs to get a full name, I suggest that you use a computed column for that, then you don't need to concatenate the names every time

```
ALTER TABLE <Your Table Name Here>
ADD [FullName] AS CONCAT(LastName, ',', FirstName, ',', MiddleName);
```

Comment: in my result is required to NAME, RecordDate,EmployeeNO, TimeIN and TimeOut i need to separate the entries date in 2 table(TimeIn  and TimeOut)

Comment: Are you talking about the order of the columns? You can change that in the `SELECT` statement as needed.

Comment: what about i want to convert a 24 hours to 12 hour how can i do that if the convert string is need a where clause but i want to display my all data so i don't need a where clause