# how to use conversion without where clause

Tags: sql-server

My problem is my code didn't work if i have convert function because i remove the `where` clause because i want to display my all data so i don't need a `where` clause please help me. i use `convert` function because i want my time convert to 24 hours to 12 hours
this is the error(Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.)

my code is below:

```
Select B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ',' + B.MiddleName[Name] ,A.[RecordDate],B.[EmployeeNO]
CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MIN(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('I', isnull(A.[Entries],'1666-01-01 00:00:00 000'), 0), 1) > 0, CAST( SUBSTRING(ISNULL(A.[Entries],'2019-01-01 00:00:00 000'), LEN(ISNULL(A.[Entries],'2019-05-08 00:00:00 000')) - 5, 5) AS [TIME]), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeIn], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), MAX(IIF(ISNULL(CHARINDEX('O', ISNULL(A.[Entries],'1666-01-01 00:00:00 000'), 0), 1) > 0, CAST(SUBSTRING(ISNULL(A.[Entries],'2019-01-01 00:00:00 000'), LEN(ISNULL(A.[Entries],'2019-05-08 00:00:00 000')) - 5, 5) AS [TIME]), NULL)), 100) AS [TimeOut]  
 FROM Employees  [B] inner JOIN [DTR Upload] [A] ON B.EmployeeNo = A.EmpID
GROUP by B.LastName, B.FirstName, B.MiddleName,B.[EmployeeNO], A.[recordDate] 
order by A.[recordDate] asc, B.LastName + ',' + B.FirstName + ','+ B.MiddleName asc
```

Comment: is this the continue of your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539853/how-to-covert-24-hours-to-12-hours-in-existing-data ? Has it been resolved ?

Comment: sad to say, no i don't understand their code i want to answer my simple code

Comment: This is a much simpler question,so thanks for that! But I don't understand what you are asking here. What are you putting in a where clause? I tried your converts against a fixed value from your previous question and it returned 12 hour time correctly: `declare @e varchar(100); set @e='0016930507201907:35I'` returns `7:35AM`

Comment: i use a convert function but the conversion function didn't work if their have a where clause

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show what doesn't work? It should not make any difference where a convert function is.

Comment: if you get conversion error, most probably you have bad data. Check your `Entries` column

Comment: if you try my code their have a error( Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string) the error said but when i put a where clause  my code become okay but i don't want to have a where clause because i want to display my all data without filtering

Comment: Ok, if that is the case then there must be something wrong with the data you are excluding with your where clause. There must be some rows where Entries does not match the same format as the ones that work.

Comment: we don't have your data. We will not be able to simulate the same error that you are experiencing. Can you provide some sample data that will cause the conversion error ?

Comment: where B.[EmployeeNO] = '001693' if i use this my program is okay
i think my problem is if there have a blank or null in 1 data it will become error but i don't know how to solve it but if  i remove the convert function in my code my code is fine i dont know what the problem of my code

Comment: Ok so you are now debugging it. What I would do is create a small script that creates a temp table, inserts some of the data that works and some that doesnt, show your select statement that does the conversion against it, and we should be able to help. I tried null and empty with what you have and it still works. I do notice that your ISNULL() functions have a second value that is different format to the source data, so that might be part of the issue.

Comment: so what will i do please help me sorry if my English is poor

Comment: You are converting the last few characters of `Entries` to `time`. if that sting is not in `HH:MM` or the `hour` value exceeded `23` or `minute` value exceeded `60`, it will cause conversion error. Check your data

Comment: until now this question i cant answer please help me